# When is it not safe to apply the approximation (1+a)^N = 1+Na (for a<<1)?

Tags: approximation-theory

For example, consider the following equation where $|k|<<1$, $N$ is a positive integer ranging from 1 to 100,000) and $k,N$ are both real.
$$
\left(\frac{1+k}{k} \right)\left[(1+k)^N-1 \right]
$$
Route (1) using the (?Bernoulli?) approximation immediately we get
$$
\left(\frac{1+k}{k} \right)\left[(1+Nk)-1 \right]
\rightarrow
\left(\frac{1+k}{k} \right)Nk
\rightarrow
(1+k)N
\rightarrow
N+kN.
$$
Route (2) rearranging before using the approximation we get
$$
\left(\frac{1}{k} \right)\left[(1+k)^{N+1}-(1+k) \right]
\rightarrow
\left(\frac{1}{k} \right)\left[(1+Nk+k)-(1+k) \right]
\rightarrow
\frac{Nk}{k}
\rightarrow
N.
$$
Clearly use of the approximation in this particular case gives ambiguous results.  But are there general guidelines on when it is or isn't safe to use this approximation - either in examples similar to the one above or, more generally, to a wider range of problems?

Comment: It is the Bernoulli Inequality.

Comment: The results don't seem ambiguous: one is $N$ and the other is $(1+k)N$; aren't those approximately the same when $k<\!<1$?

Comment: @Steven yes I thought about that but that is like saying that a good approximation of $1+nK$ is $1$.

Comment: What are $n$ and $K$?

Comment: @Steven In my particular application N is a positive integer of the order of 1,000 to 100,000. k is a negative or positive real number of the order 2 x 10^-12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I'm assuming $N\ge1$ and that $k$ is positive.) I wouldn't try to use this approximation when $Nk>1$. When $Nk \le 1$, it's true that $(1+k)^N  = 1 + Nk + O(N^2k^2)$ - in other words, there exists a constant $C$ such that $|(1+k)^N - (1+Nk)| \le CN^2k^2$. So the approximation is best when $k \ll 1/N$, not just $k \ll 1$.

This also helps to explain why the two answers are compatible: if you carry the error terms when you approximate, you'll see that the two approximations are $N+kN + O(N^2k)$ and $N+O(N^2k)$, respectively. In other words, the potential error from the approximation is greater than $kN$, so that term isn't significant.

Comment: Thanks, "potential error" seems like a useful concept in this situation, but can you point me to how it is calculated?

Comment: Taylor's theorem, applied to the function $f(x)=(1+x)^N$ at $x=0$, tells us that $(1+x)^N = 1 + Nx + \frac12N(N-1)x^2 (1+\xi)^{N-2}$ for some $\xi\in[0,x]$. In particular, if $x\le1$, then $|(1+x)^N - (1 + Nx)| \le \frac12N(N-1)x^2 2^{N-2}$. (And you can clearly improve the constant at the end if you assume a smaller bound on $x$.)

Comment: Many thanks. You assumed that $k$ was positive in your answer but I am interested in $k$ negative, with $k<<1$.  If I change \(in your comment) $x \leq 1$ to $|x| \leq 1$ does everything else still apply?

Comment: Yes, as you can check. Indeed, if $-1<x<0$ then you won't even need the $2^{N-2}$ term. (By the way, "$k$ is negative" is the kind of information that it's helpful to put in the question to begin with.)

Comment: Thanks again. Yes sorry I have re-specified the example.  However, it was meant just as an example. I am interested in the application of the approximation to a wider range of problems.